# Ag- grid Selecting a parent should select the all children of it in tree data path

Tags: angular, ag-grid

I am giving the data to grid with path (Tree Data). How Ican select the children if i select the parent node in ag-grid with tree legacy.

my data looks like below:

```
[{
name: 'File',
path:['file'],
isVisible: true
},
{
name: 'Save',
path:['file'],
isVisible: true
},
name: 'Export',
path:['file'],
isVisible: False
];
```

Comment: looking for the same. got any luck ?

Answer (score 5):

**.html**

```
    <ag-grid-angular 
    ....
    (rowSelected)="rowSelected($event)" 
    .... >
    </ag-grid-angular>
```

**.ts**

```
 rowSelected(event){
      event.node.childrenAfterGroup.forEach(a=>{
           a.selectThisNode(event.node.isSelected())
     })
 }
```

***Pro Tip:*** Passing either `undefined` or `null` to `selectThisNode` makes it partially checked.

Comment: Add a short explanation what this code does and how it answers the original question

Answer (score 1):

In order to select or deselect all children nodes of a parent node, just consider the following code. I solved my problem with this.

**in .ts file:**

```
rowSelected(event: any) {
   event.node.childrenAfterGroup.forEach(node => {
     node.selectThisNode(event.node.isSelected());
   });
}
```

and add the following rowSelected event notation into  tag,

**in html:**

```
<ag-grid-angular 
....
(rowSelected)="rowSelected($event)" 
.... >
</ag-grid-angular>
```

> *P.S. I love coding :)*